# GET http://localhost:3000/api/products/undefined 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, undefined

I've been dealing from this problem for a while.

It's a MERN project I'm trying fetching one product when try accessing it from the list of products it gives me a 404 error however, if I tried putting directly the id of product in the URL it works !

it shows http://localhost:3000/product/undefined instead of http://localhost:3000/product/6376ae043f18b79b043c5b89

productScreen.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  Row,
  Col,
  Image,
  ListGroup,
  Card,
  Button,
  Form,
} from "react-bootstrap";

import Rating from "../components/Rating";
import Message from "../components/Message";
import Loader from "../components/Loader";

import { listProductDetails } from "../actions/productActions.js";

const ProductScreen = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const productId = `${encodeURIComponent(id)}`;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useNavigate();

  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);

  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
  const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProductDetails(productId));
  }, [dispatch, productId]);

  const addToCartHandler = () => {
    history(`/cart/${productId}?qty=${qty}`);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Link className="btn btn-light my-3" to="/">
        Go Back
      </Link>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : error ? (
        <Message variant="danger">{error}</Message>
      ) : (
        <Row>
          <Col md={6}>
            <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid />
          </Col>
          <Col md={3}>
            <ListGroup variant="flush">
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <h3>{product.name}</h3>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Rating
                  value={product.rating}
                  text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`}
                />
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>Price: ${product.price}</ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                Description: {product.description}
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
          </Col>
          <Col md={3}>
            <Card>
              <ListGroup variant="flush">
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Price:</Col>
                    <Col>
                      <strong>${product.price}</strong>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Status:</Col>
                    <Col>
                      {product.countInStock > 0 ? "In Stock" : "Out Of Stock"}
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>

                {product.countInStock > 0 && (
                  <ListGroup.Item>
                    <Row>
                      <Col>Qty</Col>
                      <Col>
                        <Form.Control
                          as="select"
                          value={qty}
                          onChange={(e) => setQty(e.target.value)}
                        >
                          {[...Array(product.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
                            <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                              {x + 1}
                            </option>
                          ))}
                        </Form.Control>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                )}

                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Button
                    onClick={addToCartHandler}
                    className="btn-block"
                    type="button"
                    disabled={product.countInStock === 0}
                  >
                    Add To Cart
                  </Button>
                </ListGroup.Item>
              </ListGroup>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductScreen;
```

productAction.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
} from '../constants/productConstants.js';
export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST });

    const { data } = await axios.get('/api/products');

    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};

export const listProductDetails = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST });

    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `/api/products/${id}`
    );

    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

productRoutes.js

```
import express from 'express';
import Product from '../models/productModel.js';
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import {ObjectId} from 'mongoDB';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const router = express.Router();

// @desc fetch all products
// @droute  GET /api/products
// @access public

router.get(
  '/',
  asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const products = await Product.find({});

    return res.json(products);
  })
);

// @desc fetch oneproducts
// @droute  GET /api/products/:id
// @access public

router.get(
  '/:id([0-9a-fA-F]{24})',
  asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id.trim());
    const product = await Product.findById(id);
    if (product) {
      return res.json(product);
    } else {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Product not found' });
      //throw new Error('Product not found');
    }

    //return res.json(product);
  })
);

export default router;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen';
import { CartScreen } from './screens/CartScreen';
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className='py-3'>
        <Container>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/product/:id' element={<ProductScreen />} />
            <Route path='/cart' element={<CartScreen />} />
            <Route path='/' element={<HomeScreen />} />
          </Routes>
        </Container>
      </main>

      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjkBJ.jpg)

Comment: ---Added--- this package.json  
`{  "name": "frontend",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {}}`

Comment: Your `productId` is undefined please try to console log and see if it has a correct value

Comment: @ShubhamWaje console log also return undefined

Comment: Means you are not passing id in the url. Can you share the full url you are entering in the chrome to load the `ProductScreen` component?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/product/undefined , if I manually put the id like this http://localhost:3000/product/6376ae043f18b79b043c5b89 it works fine !

Comment: Obviously you have to embed the product id on card click while redirecting. Do you have any product card listing in which when we clicking on project card it is getting redirected? If yes please share the code of that listing. :)

Comment: i found it , it works now thank you so much. i was redirecting it to a id not _id                                                                                                                                        the correct one  `<Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
     <Card.Img src={product.image} variant='top'/>
    </Link>
    <Card.Body>
    <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
     <Card.Title as ='div'> <strong>{product.name}</strong> </Card.Title>
    </Link>`